# Is there any way of of get backup of postgres db in docker container without generating sql file?

Tags: postgresql, docker, database-backups, docker-volume

I am new in Docker, I want to get a backup for my postgress database running in docker. All solutions i saw are offering to generate a dump sql script and restore db with running this script. But i dont want to do this? Is it possible backup and restore by migrating binary files of the db?

Answer (score 0):

You can build Postgres image from plain empty Postgres db image. In Dockerfile you add SQL script which runs on db initialization (docker-entrypoint-initdb.d). The SQL script contains dblink to your backed up db and commands `create table my_table as select * from my_table@remotedb`. After `docker build` you have image with backup of your original database tables.

I do something similar with Oracle with more complexity (copying only subset of original database, preserving indexes etc.). Oracle docker image differs from PG in some properties but I believe the rough idea is applicable. It is some time ago I worked with PG so I won't advise you how to migrate binary files (though I believe it would be possible too).